# from_json() returning always null values

Tags: python, pyspark, azure-databricks

I have a custom schema made for a column, for example this:

```py
_schema = StructType([
  StructField("Faa", StringType(), True),
  StructField("Foo", StringType(), True)
])
```

When I use it `df.withColumn("test", from_json(col("fieldA"), _schema))`, it returns this:

```
{
  "Faa": null,
  "Foo": null
}
```

Always, independently of each row value.

To add, the length of each row of `fieldA` is about 7.000-8.000 characters. Is there anything like a limit that thresholds the parsing of the column? What would be the best approach in this case?

Comment: Can you share a sample json document that produces the `null` values?

Comment: Please provide a [mre]

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen no sorry I cannot, but the column is a bunch of 3000 or 4000 fields, like `Foo` and `Faa`

Comment: @eyllanesc sorry see my previous comment

Answer (score 1):

I have tried the below example:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession, Row
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, from_json
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType, StructField, StringType
data = [
    ('{"Faa": "value1", "Foo": "value2"}',),
    ('{"Faa": "value3", "Foo": "value4"}',),
    ('{"Faa": "value5", "Foo": "value6"}',),
]
df = spark.createDataFrame(data, ["fieldA"])
print(df.schema)
_schema = StructType([
    StructField("Faa", StringType(), True),
    StructField("Foo", StringType(), True)
])
df_parsed = df.withColumn("fieldA", col("fieldA").cast(StringType())) \
    .withColumn("test", from_json(col("fieldA"), _schema))
df_parsed.show(truncate=False)
```

**Results:**

```
| StructType([StructField('fieldA', StringType(), True)]) |
|---------------------------------------------------------|
```

```
| fieldA                             | test             |
|------------------------------------|------------------|
| {"Faa": "value1", "Foo": "value2"} | {value1, value2} |
| {"Faa": "value3", "Foo": "value4"} | {value3, value4} |
| {"Faa": "value5", "Foo": "value6"} | {value5, value6} |
```

In the above code to handle rows in a DataFrame, you can use the ‘`Row`’ function from the '`pyspark.sql' module`. work with individual rows in your DataFrame.

For manipulating DataFrame columns, you can make use of the ‘`col`’ and ‘`from_json`’ functions from the ‘`pyspark.sql.functions`’ module.
These functions allow you to perform various operations on the columns of your DataFrame.

When you need to define the schema for your DataFrame, you can use ‘**StructType**’, ‘**StructField**’, and ‘**StringType**’ from the ‘`pyspark.sql.types`’ module.
These allow you to specify the structure and data types for the columns in your DataFrame.

Define a custom schema using  **StructType**  and  **StructField**  to specify the structure of the  **JSON**  data.

To convert the “**fieldA**” column to  **StringType**, you can use the  `col("fieldA").cast(StringType())`  function.
This helps in converting the data in the “**fieldA**” column to a  **String type**.

The from_json function is used to parse the  **JSON**  data in the “**fieldA**” column with a specific schema.
This function helps to interpret the  **JSON**  data according to the provided schema.

To create a new column named “test” containing the parsed  **JSON**  data, you can use the parsed output from the from_json function and assign it to a new column in the DataFrame.